# mongodb docker-compose replica set : no primary elected and can't reconfig cause version is too long

Tags: mongodb, docker, replicaset

I try to setup 3 replica set on the same machine (but data in different mounted volumes) with the following docker-compose

```
version: '3.8'
      services:
        mongo1:
          image: mongo:{{ mongo_version }}
          container_name: mongo1
          restart: unless-stopped
          command: ['--replSet', 'rs0', '--bind_ip_all']
          volumes:
            - '{{ mongodb_host_dir }}/db1:/data/db'
          ports:
            - 27017:27017

        mongo2:
          image: mongo:{{ mongo_version }}
          container_name: mongo2
          command: ['--replSet', 'rs0', '--bind_ip_all']
          restart: unless-stopped
          volumes:
            - '{{ mongodb_host_dir }}/db2/:/data/db'
          ports:
            - 27018:27017

        mongo3:
          image: mongo:{{ mongo_version }}
          container_name: mongo3
          command: ['--replSet', 'rs0', '--bind_ip_all']
          restart: unless-stopped
          volumes:
            - '{{ mongodb_host_dir }}/db3/:/data/db'
          ports:
            - 27019:27017
```

When I deploy it with ansible, the 3 docker machines start, rebuild their index (which are quite heavy) and then end up in a weird status with

- mongo1: SECONDARY
- mongo2: REMOVED
- mongo3: REMOVED

I tried to reconfigure the replica set but I always end up with an error

Here is my `rs.conf()`

```
{
    "_id" : "rs0",
    "version" : NumberLong(2147479187),
    "term" : 59,
    "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
    "writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault" : true,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "mongo1:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "mongo2:27018",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 0.5,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "mongo3:27019",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 0.5,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        }
    ],
    "settings" : {
        "chainingAllowed" : true,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
        "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
        "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
        "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : -1,
        "catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis" : 30000,
        "getLastErrorModes" : {

        },
        "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
            "w" : 1,
            "wtimeout" : 0
        },
        "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("61925051a11a5082883074f2")
    }
}
```

And if I try something like

```
rs.reconfig({
  "_id" : cfg._id,
  "version": 1,
    "protocolVersion" : cfg.protocolVersion,
    "writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault" : cfg.writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault,
    "members" : [cfg.members[0]],
    "settings" : cfg.settings
},{force:true})
```

I get

```
{
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1639371743, 4),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "version field value of 2147540938 is out of range",
    "code" : 103,
    "codeName" : "NewReplicaSetConfigurationIncompatible",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1639371743, 4),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to stop mongo2 and mongo3 but mongo1 is never reelected correctly

Hope you can help me as my site is down for now :-)

I am really lost

Comment: The version number is 2147479187, i.e. you would had reconfigured the replica set 2 billion times! The `members` field should contain all members, i.e. `members: cfg.members`. If you want to remove a member then use `rs.remove()` instead of `members: [cfg.members[0]]`

Comment: Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit. From what I understand the version is incremented with large number on each reconfig so it's not exactly that the replica set has been reconfigured 2 billion times.
Anyway, how can I do to reset this version 
I can't reconfigure because the version is too high
Thanks

Comment: Try `db.adminCommand({replSetReconfig: <new_config_document>})` instead of the wrapper `rs.reconfig()`. Looks like only `reconfig` increases the `version` automatically, in `replSetReconfig` you set it explicitly.

Comment: When I reconfigure a replica set then I provide `_id, version, term, members`, perhaps `term` is missing.

Comment: Nope

Again with
```
db.adminCommand({
...   replSetReconfig:{
...     "_id" : cfg._id,
...     "version": 1,
...     "term": 1,
...     "protocolVersion" : cfg.protocolVersion,
...     "writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault" : cfg.writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault,
...     "members" : [cfg.members[0]],
...     "settings" : cfg.settings
...   },
...   force: true
... })
```
I get `"version field value of 2147516535 is out of range"`

PS: I saw your coment on the removing of replica set but i just want to make the reconfig be applied for now)

Comment: I am really stuck because even if I stop my containers and recreate them, they still go and get the rs config stored.
Is there a way to clean this rs config for good ? from a secondary ?

Comment: Try `db.getSiblingDB('local').dropDatabase()` Afterwards you can initialize the replica set again with `rs.init()` And again: `"members" : [cfg.members[0]]` is wrong and pointless!

Comment: Well it did not work either. I ended up restarting fresh as my data was not that important. Thanks for your help anyway @WernfriedDomscheit